# request.getParameter and request.getQueryString yield incompatible results?

Tags: servlets, jetty

In my jetty server log, I observe the following:

07 Jan 2016 10:03:52,605 DEBUG WS.DuccHandlerProxy - N/A handle  (GET /ducc-servlet/file-contents?fname=/home/degenaro/ducc/logs/1/x+y+z.log&page=1)

07 Jan 2016 10:03:52,605 DEBUG WS.DuccHandler - N/A handleDuccServletFileContents  qs:fname=/home/degenaro/ducc/logs/1/x+y+z.log&page=1

07 Jan 2016 10:03:52,605 DEBUG WS.DuccHandler - N/A handleDuccServletFileContents  fn:/home/degenaro/ducc/logs/1/x y z.log

The code corresponding to the last two entries comprise the results of request.getQueryString() and request.getParameter("fname") respectively.

How come the latter loses the '+' character?

Comment: I did search and did not find a suitable answer.  Do you have a pointer to the answer I seek?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `request.getQueryString()` you get the query string as it is in the url bar. When you call `request.getParameter("fname")` you get the value of that parameter with any encoded symbols decoded.  `+` in a url parameter represents a space, so its decoded to space.

Comment: Thanks!  So if the input is immutable, then I suppose I'll have to parse the query string myself and abandon use of request.getParameter()?

Comment: @user2133121 Do you want the literal `+`? If you created the link, you should use urlencode function on the parameter when building the link. (It would replace `+` with `%2B` which will be translated back to literal `+` by `request.getParameter("fname")`

Comment: Changing the request is not my first choice.  And what other characters do I need to watch out for?  I did find HttpServlet documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29 which makes no mention of the different behaviours between these two methods.

Comment: The answer to my question is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding which I hope will help someone else someday.